# What is the point of ParameterSchema.AllowDBNull in CodeSmith?

Tags: codesmith

I'm currently trying to use write a simple C# wrapper class for all the stored procedures in a database.  For this I'm using CodeSmith and in particular the SchemaExplorer.

While iterating through the parameters for a stored procedure, I noticed the property ParameterSchema.AllowDBNull and wondered what this is for.  As far as I am aware, it is not possible to declare a parameter as NOT NULL and therefore NULL is always allowed to be passed to any parameter.

Through testing, it appears that AllowDBNull is always true (or at least, I have not been able to write a procedure that results in false).  So, this leads me to ask what is it for?

I've found this post from CodeSmith forums from back in 2003:
http://community.codesmithtools.com/Support_Forums/f/3/t/264.aspx

They say they will "fix" this in the next release which makes me think there is something that I am missing or not understanding about this property.

Thanks for looking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I work for CodeSmith Tools and I have updated the [forum post](http://community.codesmithtools.com/support_forums/f/3/p/264/46742.aspx#46742) from your question. I consulted with Eric about this issue and we decided that it was by design because you can always pass null into a stored procedure parameter. As part of your question, this is a property that is defined in a base class and allows you to detect on other Schema Objects (E.G., ColumnSchema) if the object is nullable.

The [CommandWrapper templates](http://www.codesmithtools.com/product/generator#templates) will generate a strongly typed class from an existing stored procedure or function. Have you had a chance to take a look at this?